# Accessing gmail atom feed when users are logged in with CAS

Tags: jquery, gmail, cas, atom-feed

I am working on a liferay portal.  Users are logged into the portal via a CAS sign on and this same CAS sign on also logs users into their gmail accounts (Single sign on).  Passwords are not imported into the portal from ldap so I do not have access to the users passwords.  I was hoping to put the gmail atom feed on the portal front page. Users would sign into the portal via the CAS login and they can see if they have unread messages right there on the front page of the portal.  If I access the atom feed using server side code then I need to supply it with the gmail username and password which I do not have access to.  So, I thought to use javascript / jquery and access the atom feed via client-side code (once the user is logged in with CAS, it doesn't ask for a password when accessing the gmail atom feed via the browser).  But I am now realizing I am restricted by cross domain policy so a client-side ajax call to the feed will not work due to this.  Is there another solution to this if the user is already authenticated with CAS but I can't explicitly supply gmail with the password?